# How to import a tsv file with SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, csv, import-from-csv

I have a tsv (tab separated file) that I would like to import with sqlite3. Does someone know a clear way to do it?

I have installed sqlite3, but not created any database or tables yet.

I've tried the command

```
.import /path/filename.tsv my_new_table
```

but it gives me the error: no such table: my_new_table.

However, from what I'd read it should create the table automatically if it does't exist. Does it mean I need to create and use a database first, or is there another trick to importing a .tsv file into sqlite?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should create the table, set a separator and import the data ([sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_files_as_csv_or_other_formats)).

Example for TSV:

`data.tsv` (tab as a separator):

```
Bob 30  1000
Wendy   20  900
```

1. Create a table and set TAB as a separator:

   ```
   sqlite> create table people (name text, param1 int, param2 int);
   sqlite> .separator "\t"
   ```
2. Import data:

   ```
   sqlite> .import data.tsv people
   ```

And the result is:

```
sqlite> select * from people;
Bob 30  1000
Wendy   20  900
```

Comment: Note that using `.separator "\t"` means that sqlite will still use csv-style rules for interpreting quotation marks, which probably isn't what you want. A better option is to use the `tabs` mode described in adius's answer.

Comment: Seems like there is some logic on the names. After .separator "\t", I also had to rename from .csv to .tsv

Comment: No need to create a table. The import will do it for you. If you are happy for every column's type to be chosen for you. I did this and everything was 'text'. This might be OK for situations where you are manually exploring data to throw away later.

Answer (score 109):

There is actually a dedicated mode for importing tab separated files:

```
sqlite> .mode tabs
sqlite> .import data.tsv people
```

Also if you include a header row in your tsv file, you can let sqlite automatically create the table.
Just use an unused table-name during import and change the tsv file to:

```
name    param1  param2
Bob 30  1000
Wendy   20  900
```

Comment: don't put a semi-colon at the end of the import statement, like I did :)

Comment: `Error: no such table: people`

Comment: `.help .mode` says its job is to “set output mode,” but `.help .import` clarifies in a note: “If neither `--csv` or `--ascii` are used, the input mode is derived
        from the `.mode` output mode”