# sqlite3 .import failing to create table

Tags: sqlite

I have seen other posts and tried the answers but it still will not create the table for me.

I simply want to import a .tab file into a new sqlite3 table on the fly.

I have tried .mode csv with a .separator '\t' and .mode tabs

I have the following command and error.

> sqlite> .mode tabs
>
> sqlite> .import /storage/mgymrek/gtex-estrs/revision/mastertables/Adipose-Subcutaneous_master.csv Temp1
>
> Error: no such table: Temp1

I have also tried

> sqlite3 -separator '\t' estr.db ".import Adipose-Subcutaneous_master.csv Temp1"
>
> Error: no such table: Temp1

Please help!

Comment: Does the `Temp1` table exist? When you run the `.tables` command, what does it show you?

Comment: Thanks for the question . No it doesn't .  Error: no such table: Temp1
sqlite> .tables
sqlite>

Answer (score 0):

[To import a CSV file in SQLit3, set the mode to csv.](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import) If it's a tab-seperate-file, you could try importing the file as shown in: [How to import a tsv file with SQLite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065872/how-to-import-a-tsv-file-with-sqlite3)

> sqlite> .mode csv
>
> sqlite> .import /storage/mgymrek/gtex-estrs/revision/mastertables/Adipose-Subcutaneous_master.csv Temp1

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is where I started .mode csv and .separator '\t' . No luck

Comment: If you want to keep the file as a TSV (tab separated values) file, then it seems you'll need to create the table before importing it. Alternatively, you can save the file as a CSV (replacing the tabs with commas).

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99183/sqlite-csv-import-wont-create-a-table-automatically), if you have an older version of SQLite this will happen. I'm not sure in which version the automatic creation of a table was implemented, but from that post if you have SQLite 3.8.9 or newer it should automatically create the table, possibly a few versions before would also do that. If you have 3.7.17 or older it won't create the table, this is the version I have and it doesn't work (I arrived here investigating why). I don't know the versions in-between, but if you're there and it's not working for you I suggest you upgrade.